# Change the background from the read pictureboxes

Tags: c#, sql, database, picturebox

```
    private void mELEEToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::vaja15.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString);
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand sda = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Uporabnik WHERE attacktype='melee' ", cn);
        reader = sda.ExecuteReader();


            while (reader.Read())
            {
                label1.Text = reader[7].ToString();
            }

            reader.Close();

        cn.Close();
    }
```

**1.)**

I got a form where i got 110 pictureboxes, in my databse I got theese rows: attacktype, role, pictureboxname. In attacktype I have either melee or ranged, role doesnt matter yet, and the row: pictureboxname contains (pictureBox1, pictureBox2) mannualy written into it.

So my reader does select every row that is type melee. I want to make theese selected pictureboxes to hide on the form, how do I do that?

Comment: i got something to add here: my idea is that when i click this menu item this happens: pictureBox1.Hide(); pictureBox2.Hide(); but only for the selected pictureboxes

Answer (score 0):

Do it as follow

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mele",melee).Value = melee (if melee is string  type "melee")
```

And your command must be as :

```
 SqlCommand sda = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Uporabnik WHERE attacktype=@melee", cn);
```

Comment: where do i insert the firs line that u wrote ?

Comment: Can you send What you wrote finally ?

Comment: sorry change cmd with sda because you used sda for command. Usally I'am using SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand :)))

Comment: sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@melee",melee).Value = melee (if melee is string  type "melee"); shows me error

Comment: If melee is a string type you should write "melee" if it's numeric you have to write melee

Comment: If melee is string type :
sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@melee",melee).Value = "melee"
if numeric
sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@melee",melee).Value = melee

Comment: And don't write What I wrote a remarq between paranthesis (if melee is string type) it was only a remarq for you

Comment: both show me an error, second  said its not generated so i did generate it and still error

Comment: i want to make those selected pictureboxes set to hide, the previous code is working

Comment: sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@melee",melee) 

Sorry

Comment: There is to methods to use this one is:
 sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@melee",melee)
Other:
 sda.Parameters.Add("@melee",MySqlDbType.VarChar,10).Value = "melee"

But I see you don't use MySql what do you use for accessing your database MySql or MsSql

Comment: its doesnt writes any line out it shows error when i click menustrip